# Are the physical and chemical properties of a molecule an average of the properties of its conformers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers

Conformers sometimes differ in chemical reactivity. For example, only certain alkyl bromide conformers have the appropriate geometry to undergo elimination via an E2 mechanism. I imagine that conformers differ in physical properties as well, for example I think they might have different dipole moments, differing abilities to form hydrogen bonds, and differing abilities to pack together (if any of these are not true please let me know), leading to different melting and boiling points.

If a molecule can rapidly convert between different conformers, are the properties of the molecule that we observe a weighted average of the properties of the conformers, with the most stable conformers contributing the most to the properties? Could there be some kind of “synergistic” effect, where, for example, two different conformers are able to hydrogen bond well with each other, leading to a lower overall boiling point than the boiling point of any individual conformer? If this synergy is present, could it lead to conformers that we would expect to be high in energy based on steric arguments actually being lower in energy than we expect due to interactions with other conformers, and due to this lowered energy, the molecules might become this conformer more frequently?

Comment: That would be yes, yes and yes and... I dunno who many questions you managed to pack in there, but your analysis seems correct. Read a bit about proteins if you wanna go down this way. For example prions, or perhaps binding of intrinsically disordered proteins.

Comment: How different do the properties of individual conformers tend to be?

Comment: It depends? And what properties? Some things can be hydrophobic in non-polar solvent and vice versa, for example.

Comment: I am thinking of properties like dipole moment, melting point, and boiling point.

Comment: See, the thing you seem to not get is difference between stuff you can get in different forms and what you can't. If you can it's not called conformers. That's pretty much why atropoisomerism was "invented".

Comment: That's why proteins can get chemists' pants in a twist ;) They defy what I said in earlier comment

Comment: Is that because a folded and unfolded protein can be viewed as different conformers of the same molecule?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140463/discussion-between-mithoron-and-akash).

Answer (score 2):

> Conformers sometimes differ in chemical reactivity. For example, only certain alkyl bromide conformers have the appropriate geometry to undergo elimination via an E2 mechanism.

Studying a reaction might suggest something about the distribution of conformers, as you point out. By investigating the reaction rate under different conditions and proposing an appropriate mechanism you can attempt to deduce the fraction of reactive molecules in the total ensemble at any given moment, and how quickly they interconvert to generate more reactive molecules.

> If a molecule can rapidly convert between different conformers, are the properties of the molecule that we observe a weighted average of the properties of the conformers, with the most stable conformers contributing the most to the properties?

The main tool chemists use to study conformers, their properties and their distribution is spectroscopy, typically the interaction of molecules with different types of electromagnetic radiation including scattering.  Separation techniques can also be useful. What you observe in your sample depends on the timescale of the experiment. If the conformers interconvert more rapidly than that timescale you observe a single average. Otherwise you might observe a superposition of the properties of different conformers, as if you were performing separate but simultaneous experiments on these conformers. Intermediate situations occur too.

> Could there be some kind of “synergistic” effect, where, for example, two different conformers are able to hydrogen bond well with each other, leading to a lower overall boiling point than the boiling point of any individual conformer?

A (well-defined) boiling point is by definition an ensemble property of a large homogeneous sample of molecules in a liquid state. So the question does not make sense.

> If this synergy is present, could it lead to conformers that we would expect to be high in energy based on steric arguments actually being lower in energy than we expect due to interactions with other conformers, and due to this lowered energy, the molecules might become this conformer more frequently?

Intermolecular interactions can play a very important role in determining preferred conformations. This can be the case whether those interactions are with other molecules or the same type.